# pixeloffset not working in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

I have created a customized google map, with a marker and customized info window.
 want the info window below the marker instead of top.
I achieved this by positioning lattitude and longitude of info window.
But I came across pixeloffset attribute in google api, but its not working.
I used

```
var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
map: map,
content: '<div>Some label</div>',
position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.890076,75.755000),
shadowStyle: 1,
padding: 0,
backgroundColor: 'rgb(57,57,57)',
borderRadius: 4,
arrowSize: 0,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
disableAutoPan: true,
hideCloseButton: true,
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-100,0)
});
infoBubble2.open(map,marker);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InfoBubble` is not a implementation of a `google.maps.InfoWindow` , there is no property `pixelOffset` for a `InfoBubble`.

But it only takes some minor changes in infobubble.js to apply this feature.

Open infobubble.js(uncompiled version) and find this code(inside the draw-function):

```
  // Adjust for the height of the info bubble
  var top = pos.y - (height + arrowSize);

  if (anchorHeight) {
    // If there is an anchor then include the height
    top -= anchorHeight;
  }

  var left = pos.x - (width * arrowPosition);
```

apply these changes:

```
  if(!this.pixelOffset 
      || !this.pixelOffset.constructor 
         || this.pixelOffset.constructor !== google.maps.Size){
    this.pixelOffset = new google.maps.Size(0,0);
  }
  // Adjust for the height of the info bubble
  var top = pos.y - (height + arrowSize) + this.pixelOffset.height;

  if (anchorHeight) {
    // If there is an anchor then include the height
    top -= anchorHeight;
  }

  var left = pos.x - (width * arrowPosition) + this.pixelOffset.width;
```